# CodeIgniter Controller problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my AdminBase.php

```
<?php

class AdminBase extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::Controller();
        $admin = $this->session->userdata('username');
        if(!isset ($admin)){
            redirect('/Site/Home');
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my Admin Controller :-

```
<?php

class Admin extends AdminBase{

    public function index(){
        echo "You are in Admin panel!!";
    }

}
```

When i browse to Admin controller, i get this error :-

`Fatal error: Class 'AdminBase' not found in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\College\application\controllers\Admin.php on line 3`

Comment: you can use the hmvc in codeingniter which is good then extends the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this line on top of Admin.php

```
<?php
// Include Base Controller
    include ('AdminBase.php');
class Admin extends AdminBase{

    public function index(){
        echo "You are in Admin panel!!";
    }

}
```

Also your base admin class should be like

```
<?php

class AdminBase extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::Controller();
        $admin = $this->session->userdata('username');
        if(empty($admin)){
            redirect('/Site/Home');
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Muhit, can you tell me why do i see `you are in admin panel` even though there is no session variable set? do you find any error with my AdminBase class?

Comment: Yes if(!isset ($admin)) is always false. because $this->session->userdata('username'); will always return a value or Boolean so it should not be "!isset()" but might be "empty()" or check null or check false etc.

Comment: using `include` inside a controller is a bad practice in CodeIgnitor, You need to create a library and then load it.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do that just created filename MY_Controller.php at application/libralies

and then create like this

```
<?php
class AdminBase extends Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::Controller();
        $admin = $this->session->userdata('username');
        if(!isset ($admin)){
            redirect('/Site/Home');
        }
    }
}
```